# Unable to post product reviews on secondary store site; displays recaptcha error but no recaptcha is present in form?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

In Magento 1.9.2.4, the product review form has no recaptcha, but won't post with the error:

```
<ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><span>The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly.</span></li></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'light',
        lang : 'en',
    };
//]]>
</script>
```

Those are the only two instances of "recaptcha" in the page source.

How can I go about resolving this issue? I'm just learning Magento.

The `POST` to http://second.first.com/second/review/product/post/id/4802/ returns status code `302 Moved Temporarily`.

By the way we have url-key product URL rewrites like http://second.first.com/second/product-url-key-value.html.

We did recently get an SSL cert. so I resent the request to https://... and got `302 Found`, but the recaptcha error persists.

We *do* have reCAPTCHA enabled in the default config under Customer Configuration > CAPTCHA, and functioning on our main/primary store/site "first.com". It posts to the same URL structure, sans https, successfully. I tried disabling it for the secondary site in particular but that didn't help, not surprisingly, as Review isn't even listed as an option for the forms to apply to. So I really haven't the slightest idea how this is happening.

Comment: Magento, by default, does not support reCAPTCHA (_I assume we're talking about Google's reCAPTCHA?_). So, your observation about the missing reCAPTCHA option under `Customer Configuration` should be correct. However, that means that this Captcha is anyway coming from some other place. If you're running two different themes I'd suggest to enable the `Template Path Hints` to first of all see where exactly the reCAPTCHA is added in the working view. You then may adapt the template (I guess the issue is just there) and add the probably missing snippet there as well.

Comment: Can you share the URL where I can see the actual error?

Comment: Well hell, the reCAPTCHA _seems_ native, blends right in. Is the Customer Configuration section there by default?

Comment: http://linen-rentaldev.premiertablelinens.com/linen_rental/review/product/list/id/5252/category/900/

Comment: Yes, `Customer Configuration` is there by default, however it comes only with a simple CAPTCHA - https://www.screencast.com/t/0Idwi39N6l. As mentioned, most likely you've missed to implement the reCAPTCHA (probably comes from a block of a 3rd party module) into all your custom themes (or a layout update in your custom theme is missing). We can just point a direction but the digging is up to you ;) You can try it from two different starting points: you can check the templates in use with the `Template Path Hints` or you can try to figure out what reCAPTCHA module is in use and go by its config.