# Where can I edit the post product review action/handler?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, forms, captcha, post-data

I'm trying to resolve this ridiculous issue that nobody can shed any light on [Unable to post product reviews on secondary store site; displays recaptcha error but no recaptcha is present in form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211040/unable-to-post-product-reviews-on-secondary-store-site-displays-recaptcha-error)

It's really out there, doesn't make sense, so I've got to dig deeper but Magento is so absurd to me I have no idea as to where to look. If you can please point me in the right direction while I thumb bleakly through the codebase in the meantime. Thank you.

Edit:
A post action like this is referred to by the questioner based on the other question: http://example.com/review/product/post/id/4802/ (form action when submitting a product review in frontend)

Answer (score 1):

"http://example.com/review/product/post/id/4802/" - or better "review/product/post" by default *translates* to the following controller:
`app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`.

- `review` is the name of the frontend route specified in the review module itself (can be basically anything)
- `product` is based on the name of the controller file (usually located inside the module in a folder `controllers` - in some cases `Controller` but that's a whole different story). Magento requires a controller to be named "AbcdefgController.php" - hence in this case`product` stands for the file `ProductController.php`
- `post` is based on the method name inside the controller file - again, by naming convention this translates to the method `postAction()`
- `id/4802` is then just a parameter provided along with the URL

Paths are (generally speaking) splitt up in these three sections - if you come across a shorter one i.e. "http://example.com/xyz" it means that `xyz` is the name of the route expecting a IndexController.php file containing an `indexAction()` method - hence "http://example.com/xyz" is basically the same as "http://example.com/xyz/index/index"

Note, that controllers can be overwritten by other modules which would mean that they use the same frontend route but not necessarily the (whole) original module itself.

*Some references for your further way:*

- http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ a very good article to start with to get an idea about what can be done, where it can be done and last but not least, how it can be done
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html - a little droughty every now and then but Magento's dev docs should always be considered as a relevant resource

Comment: @LinensDigital, sure, just drop a line in case there are further queries that could be handled within the scope of this topic ;)